# Problem Ajax with Laravel 5.7 and eloquent

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent, has-many

Controller path

```
Route::get('ajax-BodegasFind','AjaxController@ajaxBodegasFind')->name('ajax.bodegasfind');
```

Function "ajaxBodegasFind"

```
public function ajaxBodegasFind(Request $Request)
{
  $Tienda = new Tienda;
  $Bodegas = $Tienda::find($Request)->bodegas();
  return $Bodegas->toJson();
}
```

Ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#cod_tienda').change(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      var ctienda = $("#cod_tienda").val();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url:'{{route('ajax.bodegasfind')}}',
        data: {
          "ctienda": ctienda,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
           $('#cod_bodega').html(data);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Model Tienda

```
public function bodegas(){
  return $this->hasMany('genericlothing\Bodega','cod_tienda','cod_tienda');
}
```

Error:

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) /ajax-BodegasFind?ctienda=3:1
- Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::bodegas does not exist.
- Or Method toJson does not exist, it's very weird.

Pd:

- I already tried the csrf token and everything is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you change your code like this:

```html
public function ajaxBodegasFind(Request $Request)
{
  
  $Bodegas = (Tienda::find($Request->id))->bodegas;
  return $Bodegas->toJson();
}
```

you should have bodegas relationship method in your Tienda 
And in find method your should send id not Request object .Maybe you change your find methods . its ok if you do it
hope its help

Comment: Trying to get property 'bodegas' of non-object

Comment: Sry, it's $Request->ctienda

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a static find method on an instance object and you cannot pass request object in find method. It only takes primary key id. You should change your code the following two ways. You must have badge relation in your model(if you want to get related data) . Otherwise just call the property.

Option 1.

```
public function ajaxBodegasFind(Request $Request)
{
  $Tienda = new Tienda;
  $Bodegas = $Tienda->find($Request->id)->bodegas;
  return $Bodegas->toJson();
}
```

Option 2.

```
public function ajaxBodegasFind(Request $Request)
{
   $Bodegas = Tienda::find($Request->id)->bodegas;
   return $Bodegas->toJson();
}
```

Comment: Trying to get property 'bodegas' of non-object

Comment: Sry, es $ Request-> ctienda

Comment: What can I do for my 'ajax script' to execute in page load?